# Some of my keys are pressing other keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, hotkeys, function-keys

Preety much i am having a problem were sometimes when i press on  some keys they also press on other keys not even close to them,  some of them even activate other functions.

`s` makes turns the volume up

`x` turns the volume down

`e` clicks on `Delete` and vice versa

`3` clicks on `insert` and vice versa

`Alt` clicks on `LeftArrowKey` and vice versa

`F2` clics on `PrtSc` and vice versa

I already tried cleaning the keyboard and reinstalling it too, but this happens like from 5 in 5 minutes and then stops, allways in this cycle.
Its not a laptop and i dont have any other keyboards to see if the problem is with the keyboard only

Comment: On a laptop? Do you have an external keyboard you can plug in the laptop to confirm that that works well and the problem is the keyboard built in to the laptop?

Comment: Check Accessibility settings. That could cause what you see.

Comment: "click"? you mean "press"?

Comment: Not a laptop, and yes an external keyboard, i dont have any other keyboard to confirm it, i checked accessibility and it appears all normal but obviously is not, and yes i mean press